# Biber: get it working, cite-keys but no bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, biber

After searching for a few days now I'm getting closer but I still can't get a bibliography (APA) in my Latex document. I'm using biber in texworks on mac os 10.8.4.  After running pdflatex - biber - pdflatex, I get no bibliography in the resulting pdf, only the cite-keys are reproduced.

This is a short version of my document:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, graphicx, color}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, sortcites=true]{biblatex}                     
\DeclareLanguageMapping{dutch}{dutch-apa}       
\addbibresource{database-nl-orig.bib}
\usepackage{csquotes}   

\begin{document}
loewie \textcite{PoA}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is my .bib file:

```
@online{PoA,
author = {{Port~of~Antwerp}},
title = {De haven natuurlijker: beeldbank},
date = {2007-03-15},
url = {http://www.havenvanantwerpen.be/beeldbank},
urldate = {2010-09-20},
}
```

Does anyone see anything wrong in my code? What could be the problem?
I also can't find a .blg file in the folder.

This is what biber tells me:

```
Use of uninitialized value $bcf in substitution (s///) at script/biber-darwin line 235.
Use of uninitialized value $filename in -e at /var/folders     /42/cj12320j365bfxqs05tt4wjr0000gn/T/par-6c6f657769656d6168696575/cache-    2169e3f0bedf1bef28697a8d0c819f68e31dab72/inc/lib/Biber/Utils.pm line 116.
Use of uninitialized value $filename in concatenation (.) or string at /var/folder/42/cj12320j365bfxqs05tt4wjr0000gn/T/par-6c6f657769656d6168696575/cache-2169e3f0bedf1bef28697a8d0c819f68e31dab72/inc/lib/Biber/Utils.pm line 137.
INFO - This is Biber 1.6
INFO - Logfile is '.blg'
Use of uninitialized value $filename in concatenation (.) or string at /var/folders/42/cj12320j365bfxqs05tt4wjr0000gn/T/par-6c6f657769656d6168696575/cache- 2169e3f0bedf1bef28697a8d0c819f68e31dab72/inc/lib/Biber/Utils.pm line 146.
Entity: line 1: parser error : Document is empty
%%
^
INFO - Reading '/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/.tex'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following MWE I have no problems (no errors or warnings) from Biber 1.7 or MiKTeX 2.9.  I Have biblatex version 2013/07/15 v2.7a here.

MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{author2000,
  author  = {AuthorA},
  title   = {Title of Article},
  journal = {Name of Journal},
  year    = {2000},
}
@online{PoA,
  author  = {{Port~of~Antwerp}},
  title   = {De haven natuurlijker: beeldbank},
  date    = {2007-03-15},
  url     = {http://www.havenvanantwerpen.be/beeldbank},
  urldate = {2010-09-20},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[%
% style=authoryear
  style=apa,
 ,sortcites=true
 ,backend=biber         % to force biblatex to use biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{dutch}{dutch-apa}


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Can you please run it on your system? If you have problems please check the versions on your computer of LaTeX, Biber, Biblatex and tell it us ...

Don't forget to compile LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX.

Comment: This works on my system too!